# SVN lost synchronization between repos

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I have multiple repos that I need to chain-sync every time I have changes in the lower repos, that has been working fine forever until a few weeks back, some of the repos, when merged, give a lot of conflicts and tree conflicts, as if the merge isn't working good (because a lot of these files haven't actually changed recently).

What I've been doing is telling SVN which specific revisions to sync, I basically get the last merge between those repos and manually tell SVN to sync the remaining, this process is working fine but its too manual and eventually someone (myself included) could get it wrong and not merge everything correctly.

Is there anyway to tell SVN that the world is good and that it should relax and just take it from xxx revision on?

Comment: I would import it all to git, merge dry run, fix stuff up, and commit. But if you want to stick with the fading SVN I think you should give a specific example.

Comment: I tried to be as specific as a I could with my problem, what part should I clarify?

Comment: exact commands and output

Comment: It's a merge through Tortoise SVN UI, no command and there's no specific error, some files would give "conflict" and some other "tree conflict", however most of these files haven't changed.

Comment: just look at it fade; https://www.google.ca/trends/explore#q=Concurrent%20Versions%20System%2C%20svn%2C%20git  I have never used Tortoise but really you should be able you get a list of conflicts replace them all with whatever repo/branch/commit/version you want and finish the merge, or if you don't want to discard changes you will need to resolve with a 4 window merge tool like vimdiff... if there is no option in the graphical interface then it's time to learn the command line.... some reading; http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.branchmerge.advanced